# Is Drive API Client Library for Java functional in codename one

Tags: google-drive-api, codenameone

I'm new in Codename one. I'm developing an application that connect to Google Drive. I`d want to know if the Drive API Client Library for Java is functional in Codename one. If not, can somebody give me an advice about how to manage gdrive from Codename one?

Thanks!!!

I have read documentation about HTTP requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codename One doesn't support the Android API. We have our own API. You can use [native interfaces](https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---access-native-device-functionality-invoke-native-interfaces.html) to access native functionality like the drive API. Some API's are already exposed via a [cn1lib](https://www.codenameone.com/cn1libs.html) but the drive API isn't.